# What edition of Underworld has Rhona Mitra retconned into it?

Tags: actors, underworld

I asked this question over on [Movies SE](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/35516/15909), but haven't gotten any bites in the 3 weeks since. Maybe I'll have better luck over here.

---

While watching [**Underworld**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underworld_(2003_film)) on Netflix, I noticed that in flashbacks the original blonde Sonja ([Jazmin Dammak](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm1454251/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t24)) had been replaced by the brunette version from [Underworld: Rise of the Lycans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underworld:_Rise_of_the_Lycans) ([Rhona Mitra](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0593961/?ref_=nv_sr_1)). Obviously this was done after the release of the third film in order to make Sonja's appearance consistent across the franchise.

However, I own the Unrated Extended Cut on DVD, and it has the original blonde Sonja.

**In what version or edition of the film was Sonja's scenes retconned with the new actress?**

Answer (score 1):

The scene with Rhona Mitra was included in the 2017 remaster of the film.

> In the newly released 2017 4k remaster of Underworld, the scene where Michael recounts the events of Sonja's demise when he speaks with Lucian in the film is replaced with the actual scene from Underworld: Rise of the Lycans instead of the original flashbacks used in the 2003 version.
>   <sub>[Underworld (2003) Trivia - IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0320691/trivia?item=tr3278270)</sub>